# protractor can not start webdriver session

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor

Please help!

Hi there

I could not run protractor test, thought chrome is pop up with a blank page

In the error message it says webdriver could not be started

```
✗ protractor config.js --troubleshoot true
[16:32:54] D/launcher - Running with --troubleshoot
[16:32:54] D/launcher - Protractor version: 5.2.0
[16:32:54] D/launcher - Your base url for tests is http://localhost:9000
(node:977) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[16:32:54] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:32:54] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[16:32:54] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
(node:977) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): WebDriverError: Cannot define class using reflection
(node:977) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[16:32:54] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: Cannot define class using reflection
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/lzt/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.1/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/lzt/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.1/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/home/lzt/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.1/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
[16:32:54] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

### Bug report

- Node Version: `8.1.1`
- Protractor Version: `5.2.0`
- Angular Version: `1`
- Browser(s): `chrom`
- Operating System and Version `ubuntu`
- Your protractor configuration file

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const protractor_1 = require("protractor");
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 25000
    },
    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    specs: [
        '../../features/login/login.feature'
    ],
    onPrepare: () => {
        protractor_1.browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        protractor_1.browser.manage().window().setSize(1600, 1000);
    },
    cucumberOpts: {
        compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
        strict: true,
        format: ['pretty'],
        require: [
            '../../features/**/*.ts'
            // '../../stepdefinitions/loginPage.ts',
            // '../../support/*.ts'
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you update webdriver-manager before test run?
Let's try to `webdriver-manager update`

Did you try to run that on node v6?

https://github.com/angular/protractor#compatibility

Answer (score 0):

- Try running by removing `seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',` from your code.
- Install **LTS** version of nodejs than installing latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the local protractor installation.

`npm install protractor --save-dev`

Add this to the package.json:

`"scripts": {
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor config.js",
  },`

and run:

`npm run update-webdriver
npm run protractor`